# Calling a mixin's method on an object that doesn't include that mixin

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I'd like to use some handy util methods; in particular `Enumerable#to_a` on objects that satisfy the `Enumerable` contract (i.e. implement `each`), but that do not include `Enumerable`.

I've figured out that this seems to work:

```
Enumerable.instance_method(:to_a).bind(obj).call
```

But this seems to be really wordy and un-Rubyesque.  Is there a better/cleaner/faster way of doing this?
I'd prefer not modifying the underlying object to avoid unintentional consequences.

Essentially, I'm looking for javascript's `apply` or `call`.

**Edit:** My motivation for this is essentially encapsulation: I'd like to do this to objects in classes I didn't write, don't control, don't really need to understand in depth, and may react badly to having their own methods possibly replaced by a generic implementation.  I realize that just including Enumerable will work in most cases, but when it goes wrong it's liable to be a pain to debug, so if there's a simple way to get mixin benefits without being so invasive, I'd prefer that.

Comment: Why are you not considering just to include Enumerable? What's wrong with it?

Comment: The class is part of a library I don't control, and as a matter of general best practice, I'd like to minimize messing with its internals.  Basically, there's no reason for me to overwrite any existing methods on the class and possibly affect other consumers of that class.  I mean, it's not very likely; but why risk obscure bugs if there's some other way?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like for whatever reason you don't want to modify the class definition to `include Enumerable` but you can also of course just extend specific instances.

So you have indicated that `obj` implements `each` so you can just do this:

```
obj.extend(Enumerable).to_a
```

Ah, from your original question I thought the goal was to just not modify the class, so extending the instance was the most logical solution. However, it sounds like you don't want to modify the class or any instance.

I would do the following then:

```
obj.to_enum.to_a
```

Comment: This avoids extending all instances of the object, but it still violates the objects encapsulation:  OK; but not ideal.  Also, it's probably going to be quite a slow solution if I do this all over the place.